# Azure synapse equivalent commands

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

Looking for below mentioned equivalent command in Azure synapse analytics notebook. Below is from databricks.

```
''''1.spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true")   
''''2.spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled","true")   
''''3.spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled","true")
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some `Delta cache` and `auto` optimization features which are applicable to Databricks only. Databricks is code oriented while Synapse allows UI based analytics.

Synapse is a separate data Analytics service provided by Azure which has different feature sets. It's not mandatory that Databricks and Synapse will share same features.

**Synapse Apache Spark allows you to optimize components like data serialization, joins, shuffle, job execution, etc.** These components are different from Databricks but the objective are quite similar.

You can learn more in details about [Optimize Apache Spark jobs in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-performance).

Comment: Thanks UtkarshPal for the info. Could you please let me know, Cache enabling command in sprak scala.

Comment: As per my knowledge caching and shuffle are enabled for Apache Spark Pools in Azure Synapse by default. refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/apache-spark-for-azure-synapse-incluster-caching-and-shuffle-service-preview/

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.